# Two-factor fill bar plot displaying double bars for one factor when the other factor is 0

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `geom_col` plot with three x-values and a two-factor fill. When one of factors is 0, the other factor shows up on the plot as two bars - or one wide bar. Please see below screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of plot]

And the code used to create it:

```
data_2021_v2 %>%
  group_by(member_casual, rideable_type, day_of_week) %>% 
  summarize(number_of_trips=n()) %>% 
  arrange(member_casual,day_of_week,rideable_type) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(rideable_type,number_of_trips, fill=member_casual)) +
  facet_wrap(~day_of_week) +
  geom_col(position='dodge') +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('dodgerblue4','darkorange2')) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45))
```

The value I'm having an issue with is "Docked". There is only one row where a "member" used a "docked" bike and it is on (ironically) Wednesday. I don't want that wide orange bar, it should just be a single orange bar with empty space next to it (like Wednesday). See below tibble:

```
   member_casual rideable_type day_of_week number_of_trips
   <ord>         <chr>         <ord>                 <int>
 1 member        Classic       Monday               270561
 2 member        Electric      Monday               145598
 3 member        Classic       Tuesday              298616
 4 member        Electric      Tuesday              166854
 5 member        Classic       Wednesday            306998
 6 member        Docked        Wednesday                 1
 7 member        Electric      Wednesday            170123
 8 member        Classic       Thursday             287999
 9 member        Electric      Thursday             163484
10 member        Classic       Friday               281750
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify in your dataframe that the `number_of_trips` on the other days (exept Wednesday) are equal to `0` for `Docked`.

If you run your code again afterwards, the result is (in my example just for a couple of days):

[image]

If there is only a `Docked` for `member` but not for `casual`, ggplot sets the width of the middle column to the same as for the other two (`Classic` and `Electric`).

Or even simpler: substitute the arguments in `geom_col`:
`geom_col(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"))`

```
  data_2021_v2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(rideable_type, number_of_trips, fill=member_casual)) +
  facet_wrap(~day_of_week) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('dodgerblue4','darkorange2')) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45))
```

[image]

However, the alignment of the middle column gets messed up using this method, maybe somebody knows how to fix this (there is an option using `position_dodge2`, however, this centers the column to the middle)